# How can I vertically stack different elements in CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css

Newbie to CSS so bear with me. I am trying to vertically stack different items in HTML/CSS and can't get them to stack vertically with custom spacing. Here is what I have so far.

```
<p id="loginView">
        <input type="text" id="usernameField">
        <div></div>
        <input type="password" id="passwordField">
        <button id="loginButton">Login</button>
</p>


#loginView {
    text-align: center;
}
```

The output is all of the fields, username, password and button horizontally viewed. I am trying to get them stacked vertically and centered properly.

[Here is what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbgLu.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot put a `<div>`inside a `p` tag.
2. You could just change all the children of `#loginView`to `display:block` like so:

```css
#loginView {
  text-align: center;
}

#loginView>* {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="loginView">
  <input type="text" id="usernameField" />
  <div></div>
  <input type="password" id="passwordField" />
  <button id="loginButton">Login</button>
</div>
```

Additional: For centering stuff and aligning it in a profound way I would suggest using flexbox, its easy and can be used for a lot of different things:

https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/

Comment: Thanks. This works for centering vertically however..how can i add spacing in between the items in the loginView?

Comment: "how can i add spacing"?  SE items are supposed to be limited to one question each.  But you might look into the CSS for "margin, margin-top, etc.

Comment: @Nick just add margin-bottom to the inputs, you can also check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dispaly: flex;` to get your items vertically aligned. Also I would advise you to use classes instead of id to reference your css styles. This is a sample code. Hope it helps you

HTML

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-start justify-content-center">
  <input class="m-2" type="text" id="usernameField" />
  <input class="m-2" type="password" id="passwordField" />
  <button class="m-2" id="loginButton">Login</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.align-items-start {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.justify-content-center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.m-2 {
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
```

JS Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/SJ_KIllshot/dwkxo1va/

Answer (score 0):

You should use the semantic HTML

```css
.formWrapper {max-width: 400px; margin:0 auto;}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

input {width: 100%;margin-bottom: 10px;}
```

```html
<form class="formWrapper">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="usernameField">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" id="passwordField">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group text-center">
    <button id="loginButton">Login</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also just put `<br>` tags in between each element within `<p>`:

```
    <p id="loginView">
        <input type="text" id="usernameField">
        <br>
        <input type="password" id="passwordField">
        <br>
        <button id="loginButton">Login</button>
   </p>
```

Comment: While technically you can do this, I would suggest avoiding the use of line break tags (br) and instead use css. If the inputs and button are defined as block-level elements with a bottom margin set, you will get the same result with much cleaner markup. Also having these elements inside a <div> tag instead of that paragraph <p> tag is more correct.